# How to write SQL statement output to TXT file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, stored-procedures

I want to write a SQL statement that writes its output to a text file. I am using below statement but I want to do with a stored procedure.

This is the SQLCMD statement that I am using:

```
SQLCMD -S DATABASE\SQLSERVER2008Express -d Mydb -U sa -P triple 
       -Q "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE" -h-1 -b 
       -o "\\MyShare\ABHI\SCANNERMANIFEST.TXT" -s "," -W
```

So can you please tell me how I can do this with a SQL statement? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: WHY? SQL Server already has methods...at least look up your search engine with MSDN and attempt to search

Comment: @clifton_h sorry but i can't find any good resource so i write here..

Comment: I will give you some credit, the info is not as easily googled as it was in my head. There are a number of methods, some requiring administrative, some sysadmin roles, and some that are easy. Here is one method you can call using [sqlcmd - Pinal](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/12/sql-server-automatically-store-results-of-query-to-file-with-sqlcmd/)

Answer (score 0):

If you enable (reconfigure) the use of xp_cmdshell, you can start an OS command/batch. But this stored system procedure needs privileges so you may not able to use it...
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx](http://How%20to%20enable%20xp_cmdshell)

Here is another solution with FileSystemObjects: http://devwithdave.com/SQLServer/stored-procedures/SQLServer-StoredProcedures--HOW-TO-WRITE-TO-A-TEXT-FILE.asp

But the 'nice' way to set up and call a SSIS package, anyway...